# help with this query It shows repeated records and It is not working?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a sql statement to retrieve all the messages with user_id_user = '3' and status = '2' but I get repeated records I dont know why, I am stuck with it

```
My tables  are this 




    message
    id_message   title   content      date   user_id_user status
    -------------------------------------------------------------               

    user
    id_user   name  
    ----------------


    message_has_user
    message_id_message   user_id_user   
    ----------------------------------
```

my mysql query but I get repeated records I dont know why, I am reading tutorial also any help really appreciated

```
SELECT  
message.title,
message.content,
message.date,
message.id_message,
message_has_usuario.user_id_user,
message.status,
user.name
FROM
message ,
message_has_usuario
INNER JOIN user ON message_has_usuario.user_id_user = '3'
WHERE
message.status = '2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a Cartesian product because you're not joining all your tables accurately.
You're joining USER and MESSGAE_HAS_USERIO but you're not doing any joins on MESSAGE

Quick Example _ I assume those relationships are correct.

```
SELECT *
FROM Message M
INNER JOIN Message_Has_User MAU on M.MessageID = MAU.MessageID
INNER JOIN User U ON MAU.UserID = U.UserID AND U.UserID = M.User_Id_User
WHERE MAU.userID = '3'
AND M.Status = '2'
```

I neither endorse or will admit that I used a Select *. Darn it all to heck that I even wrote it. /hides

Comment: I dont know why but It just returns two records?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
FROM message 
JOIN message_has_usuario
    on message_has_usuario.message_has_usuario = message.message_has_usuario
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select message.*
from message, user
where user.id = 3
and user.id = message.user_id_user
and message.status = 2
```

Your not using INNER JOIN correctly.  This should work for you!!  Also what is the point of the message_has_user table?  I looks redundant in this case since you can store the user_id directly on the message table.  A user can have many messages, ie. One-To-Many.